# Android: how to Dismiss progressdailog using intents

Tags: android, android-intent, progressdialog

I have two activities , in `activityA` I have a icon ,clicking that icon i am sending an intent to other `activityB`, that is invoking the facebook page (custom dailog), since the `fbdailog` is taking time to load i am trying to implement `progressdailog`, below is my code

```
ImageView faceBookIntegration = (ImageView) activity
                .findViewById(R.id.facebookintegration);
        faceBookIntegration.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Constants.isLayoutTouched = true;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    CityAttractions.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CityAttractions.this, "","Please wait...", true);
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    Intent menuSettingsIntent = new Intent(CityAttractions.this, ShareOnFacebook.class);
                    menuSettingsIntent.putExtra("facebookMessage", "Msg");
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(menuSettingsIntent).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 1);                  

                    break;              
                }                       
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
```

The problem is after posting or cancelling the `fbdailog` , the `progressdailog` is still visible , how can i dismiss the `progreessdailog` from `activityA`. Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can use dialog.dismiss(); After startActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onActivityResult()` of ActivityA do:

```
if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: @David..so no need to set any value in onActivityResult()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You start the `ShareOnFacebook` activity using `startActivityForResult()`. This will cause your activity to "wait" until the `ShareOnFacebook` activity is completed. When that happens, your activity will get the onActivityResult() callback. This is where you know that the `ShareOnFacebook` activity is done, so you can dismiss your progress dialog.

Comment: yeahh...itz working...but the problem is ,the spinner is not spinning since it is running on Uithread...is there any way to make the spinner spin?

Comment: what i was thingking is , when i start my ShareOnFacebook i implemented progressbar and getting the facebookdailog from background(using asyncTask)..here the problem is iam getting the spinner but not the dailog...here is my code http://pastebin.com/r4q7YjBm  ...u have any idea what am i doing wrong

Comment: Well, this is definitely broken. You can't do this in `onCreate()`: `Looper.prepare(); new MyFetchTask().execute(); Looper.loop();`. If you are using `AsyncTask` you don't need that Looper stuff. Take it out. You are messing with the Main Looper on the Main (UI) thread, that's bad.

Comment: Also, you've started a ProgressDialog in ActivityA and then another one in `ShareOnFacebook`. You only need one of these.

Comment: i removed the looper ..still itz not shoeing fb feed dailog

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21772/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-teekib)

Comment: Let me know if you've figured this out or if you need more help.

Comment: i tried with all...still itz not working..with contentview without content view...not sure where iam doing wrong...i can see the progressbar when using asynctask..but fb feed dailog is not comming...